# Python Version in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I am using Windows in my local machine and i use Spyder 5.1.5 in Anaconda. Within Spyder, the python version 3.9.7; IPython version is 7.29.0.
[image]

When i ran the code below with my local machine, I never ran into the problem below.

**Problem:**
I installed the same version of python in docker (Python 3.9.7 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/)).

This is what the dataframe `df_ts` looks like

```
                    0
event123      2019-04-01 09:30:00.635
event000      2019-04-01 09:32:56.417

df_ts.dtypes
0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

When i tried to run the line below within docker

```
df_ts.idxmin(axis=0).values[0]
```

I got the error below. I am expecting it to return the index of min here. Note that I never got any error, if I run it within my local machine not docker.
**I am starting to wonder if the python version 3.9.7 I installed in docker is the same as the python 3.9.7 in Spyder.**

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype
```

This is how my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y && \
    dnf distro-sync -y

RUN yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum install openssl-devel libffi-devel bzip2-devel -y

RUN yum install wget -y && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    tar xvf Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.9*/ && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
    make altinstall

RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 /usr/local/bin/pip3

ARG USER=centos
ARG V_ENV=boto3venv
ARG VOLUME=/home/${USER}/app-src
```

Comment: it works for me: Python 3.9.7, pandas 1.3.4